# Kubuntu stuck at flashing logo boot screen

Tags: boot, kubuntu, laptop, 15.10

My week old laptop is installed with a dual boot Windows 7 / Kubuntu.
On my Kubuntu I've had the issue of the computer not waking up from sleep after closing the screen/lid. I read online that changing the display driver should fix the problem (http://wafflesatnoon.com/ubuntu-suspend-wont-wake-up-my-quest/). 
After this I was able to get some responsiveness from my computer (cursor was visible and keyboard commands worked) but still a blank screen.

I tried hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1 and indeed it got me to the terminal screen.
This is where I messed up. Not knowing how to get back to the desktop environment I tried the first solution I saw on google which was using `startx` with some parameters I can't remember or find again in google. Anyway, the command didn't finish and looked stuck for a long time so I did a manual reboot and now Kubuntu won't get past the splash screen with the blinking logo. It would just blink and then pause, I tried giving it time, no help.
I Also tried booting into recovery (successfully) and running `dpkg`, still no help.

Edit:
I managed to get into user console and when I run startx I get this message :
Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf Undefined screen "amd-screen" referenced by ServerLayout "amd-layout". 
... 
Fatal server error: 
(EE)  no screens found (EE)

Comment: try running this command `sudo rm .Xauthority` then log try logging in.

Comment: Since I can't really boot it up, should I run it using a Live USB or through recovery?

Comment: This didn't help, please see edit for new information.

Comment: i think you need to go back to your old driver.  this command will show your drivers for your GPU`sudo ubuntu-drivers list`